# Wordpress login page not display

Tags: login

i am trying to access my admin panel but i cannot. An error is occur which i will show you in screenshot. This error is occur because i forgot my password and try to login many time.

my website is hosting on free domain that's why i cannot access cpanel kindly tell me its solution.

[image: Here is the error while i access my admin panel]

when i commonly search my website it shown me **error establishing database connection**.

Comment: Check your config database and reload the page without cache :D

Comment: actually it is free hosting website in which don't have config file but database is exist.

Comment: You can find the solution here: https://www.wpbeginner.com/common-wordpress-errors-and-how-to-fix-them/#databaseconnection

Comment: yes solution is there but he accessing wp-config file which i dont have in my database and i cannot access my cpanel because my hosting is free.

Comment: You can login cpanel and create a FTP account to manage your web.

Answer (score 0):

As you can't get access to wp-config, try following these steps:

1. [Download](https://wordpress.org/download/) the newest version of WordPress.
2. Unpack it. Browse through the unpacked archive. Then delete the
   “wp-content” folder.
3. Connect to your site via FTP.
4. Head to the main WordPress root.
5. Upload the new WordPress files. Overwrite all the previous files.

Now, go back to your site. You will find that the issue has been fixed.